# Modifying a method and using params in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete

Recently I started using https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

It works great, but I was trying to set a scope for the results that I was autocompleteing, in this question I got a good answer: [Scoping the results for rails3 jquery autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858816/scoping-the-results-for-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

Using Claudio's code I've successfully scoped as such:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    autocomplete :post, :title

    def get_items(parameters)
        Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end
```

This works because I'm overwriting the plugin's get_items method. Which you can see here: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/commit/b3c18ac92ced2932ac6e9d17237343b512d2144d#L1R84 (I have a version before this commit, so get_items still works for me).

The problem with my scope, is the autocomplete functionality no longer works. When the person starts typing, the list specified in get_items just pops up, rather than items being suggested from that list.

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with my overwriting method. Any ideas?

Best,
Elliot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just made me realize that overriding get_items is not as flexible as it should be.

Your code is missing the use of parameters[:terms]

Something like this should make it work:

```
def get_items(parameters)
  Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(['title LIKE ?', "#{parameters[:term]}%"]
end
```

This is totally unfriendly, I'll try and work on something that makes more sense

Or, maybe a :scope option for the autocomplete declaration makes more sense?

Comment: Thanks dabit! I'll be trying this as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 0):

What if you have autocomplete for multiple fields though?  For example, say you want to apply it to both title and author.  How would you rewrite the following so it could serve both?

autocomplete :note, :title, :full => true
autocomplete :note, :author, :full => true

def get_items(parameters)
    Note.select("distinct title").where(["title LIKE ?", "#{parameters[:term]}%"])
  end

Currently that only works for the title field.  It kills the autocomplete for the author field.