# Autocomplete_field with results filtered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

Using Rails 3.1.1. & 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

I think this question should be quite simple for anyone using the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem but I can't find any info on it on www. I have a very straightforward setup of the rails3-jquery-autocomplete and it is working fine.

Using:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :query, autocomplete_search_result_query_search_results_path %>
```

where *query* is a column in my search_result table.

The search_results table also have a status_id-column where 1 = OK and 2 = NOT OK.

Thus, I want :query to be filtered so that only queries where status_id = 1 is fetched. How can I do that? As it is now all queries are fetched.

Putting it simple I want ":query" to equal `select query where status_id = 1`.

Controller:

```
  autocomplete :search_result, :query, :full => true
```

Routes:

```
  resources :search_results, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create], :path => 'sokresultat' do
    get :autocomplete_search_result_query, :on => :collection
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I should probably used :scope but I could never make that work. Instead this ticket solved the problem for me [Rails gem rails3-jquery-autocomplete how to scope by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244515/rails-gem-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-to-scope-by-user)