# Rails 3 rails3-jquery-autocomplete search by several fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, named-scope

I am using **rails3-jquery-autocomplete** plugin.

I would like to search by several attributes, for instance **title** and **app_number**.

What I tried:

in model:

```
class Eclaim < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_by_number, ->(query){ 
      (query ? where(["app_number LIKE ?", '%'+ query + '%']) : {})
  }
end
```

in controller:

```
class ClaimsController < ApplicationController
   autocomplete :eclaim, :title,  :extra_data => [:app_number], :scopes => [:search_by_number]
end
```

But when I am using auto complete field I get error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/models/eclaim.rb:16:in `block in <class:Eclaim>'
```

It looks like the plugin doesn't assing **query** variable.

Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

hope this helps:
[Rails gem rails3-jquery-autocomplete: How do I query multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866391/rails-gem-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-do-i-query-multiple-fields)

That error means `Eclaim.search_by_number()` was called without any arguments.  Rather curious indeed.  Let me know if the link above assists you in solving this.

Note that `:extra_data` is only setting extra attributes you want returned in the autocompleter results via the JSON response.

**Update**: Try this in your controller, adjusting for `:term`

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
   super(parameters)
   items = Eclaim.search_by_number(params[:term])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have seen it )) If I do **Eclaim.search_by_number('myquery')** in console it works. But it doesn't work automatically with autocomplete plugin. Maybe I don't understand something? What Can I do with **Eclaim.search_by_number('myquery')**?

Comment: Maybe Should I play around redefine **get_autocomplete_items** method?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244515/rails-gem-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-to-scope-by-user  You may need to override `get_autocomplete_items(parameters)` in your controller.

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858816/scoping-the-results-for-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-plugin  It seems like the way to go, you can then do `items = Eclaim.search_by_number(params[:foo])` making sure you adjust for `:foo` =)

Comment: overriding that method fails for me too. I got a strange error **NoMethodError (undefined method `collect' for true:TrueClass):**