# How to bring extra_data from join tables on rails3_jquery_autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have a association **User belongs_to Role** and want to search users by **name** using rails3_jquery_autocomplete. And I want to show some values of **Role** after select a user.

Here is my controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
   autocomplete :user, :name, scopes: [:join_role], 
   extra_data: [:address, :email]
```

And here are my models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :email
  scope :join_role, joins(:role)


class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :level
```

How can I get the name and level values in the user autocomplete search?

I can't add **:name**, **:level** on the **extra_data** option neither **:role** because it will return a sql error.

Here [rails3-jquery-autocomplete-search-by-several-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123749/rails-3-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-search-by-several-fields) says that I could override the **get_autocomplete_items** method but dont know how.

Something like that?

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
    super(parameters)
    result = []
    User.join_role.where('....').each do |user|
      result << {id: user.id, label: user.name, role: user.role.name, 
        address: user.address, email: user.email, level: user.role.level }
    end
    result
  end
```

But it result in "undefined method `id' for Hash..."

Comment: So far I am using a workaround. Returning only id and name, calling the rest info using ajax on the **railsAutocomplete.select** event.